# Rewrting Triggers from Oracle to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have to rewrite code that was generated in TOAD DATA MODELER on Oracle Data Base to PostgreSQL. I have two examples:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ts_Kluby_jezdzieckie_KlubyJe_0 BEFORE INSERT
ON Kluby_jezdzieckie FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.ID_klubu := KlubyJezdzieckieS.nextval;
END;
```

And the second one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tsu_Adresy_AdresyS AFTER UPDATE OF ID_adresu
ON Adresy FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010,'Cannot update column ID_adresu in table Adresy as it uses sequence.');
END;
```

I don't understand PostgreSQL's triggers yet, and i'm hoping for some help, have a great evening, Adam

Comment: See [Sequence Manipulation Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) and [Reporting Errors and Messages](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE)

Answer (score 0):

The first one is assigning a to value to ID_klubu from the sequence KlubyJezdzieckieS. In Postgres this would be
:new.ID_klubu = nextval('KlubyJezdzieckieS');
However, the trigger is not needed. In Postgres v10 and later define the column as `generated identity`. This would accomplish the same and eliminates the trigger.

The second raises a user defined exception where the SQLCode -20010 is a user defined exception  Postgres would be:

```
Raise Exception '-20010, Cannot update column ID_adresu in table Adresy as it uses sequence.';
```

Even better define the column as

```
ID_adresu integer generated always as identity
```

and just eliminate the trigger.